# How would I figure out - TSS of Y, Yi and XiYi from the following information?

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, linear

I came across an analogous question when revising and have no clue how to approach it.

The Given information is
 ΣXi= 20, ΣYi=40 Σ(Xi-x̅)²= 40, Σ(Xi-x̅)(Yi-nȳ)=20 and n=20.

The question requires working out Σ(Yi-ȳ)², (Xi-x̅) and Yi(xi-x̅) from what is given.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem feasible to calculate $\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}})^2$. And in the third sum, is it $\bar{y}$ or $n\bar{y}$?

Comment: What do you think about sample variance of $y$? Seems like we lack information.